# Grails external configuration logging

Tags: tomcat, grails, log4j

Whenever I deploy a production application that has an error with an [externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) I receive the following message in the Tomcat log:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper)
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.                                                       
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Apparently the externalized configuration is processed prior to log4j being initialized properly and therefore no appenders are available to accept the messages from `ConfigurationHelper`.

Is there a way to pre-initialize log4j to capture these messages before the standard Grails log4j initialization takes place?

Comment: You're hitting this on the exact same day as I am.  I don't have an answer for you yet, but if I find one, I'll post it.  That's some excellent diagnostic digging you did there.  Thanks.  Can I assume you're doing this with Grails 2.0.3 ?

Comment: @mgkimsal Yes I am experiencing this with Grails 2.0.3.

Comment: I've got mine a bit different now, but still broken.   
  
    Configuring Spring Security UI ...  
    ... finished configuring Spring Security UI  
    
    
    Configuring Spring Security Core ...  
    ... finished configuring Spring Security Core  
    
    May 23, 2012 5:21:07 PMorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart

with nothing in the stacktrace.log file.  :/

BTW, just tried grails 2.0.4, same behaviour.  There was nothing in the 2.0.4 changelog referencing configuration, but thought I'd try anyway.

Comment: @mgkimsal I enabled pre-initialization logging and found that my external configuration file that I copied from a production environment had incorrect file permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to enable pre-initialization logging by creating a file in `$CATALINA_BASE\lib\log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CA                                                          
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender                                  
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout                             
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa} %c%n%p: %m%n
```

This allowed initial messages to be logged to the console.  In the default Tomcat configuration they will be logged to the `$CATALINA_BASE\logs\catalina.out` file.

Grails initialization did override these initial settings with the settings from `Config.groovy` or the external configuration file.

My external configuration file had incorrect permissions and could not be loaded.

Comment: what are 'correct' permissions then?  Mine are readable - *properties* files seem to get parsed, but not *groovy* config files.

Comment: @mgkimsal In my case the config file changed owner from the Tomcat userid to my userid when I copied the file.  Since the permissions were rwx------ it couldn't even open the file.

Answer (score 0):

[This blogger](http://micharg.blogspot.com/2012/01/log4jspring-warning-no-appenders-could.html) recommends checking `web.xml` to ensure that the `log4j` listener is listed first. Grails generates `web.xml` during the WAR creation process but it may be worth a look.